# Entity Framework & Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, include

All
Please help me make include() work in the following case:

```
ctx.Messages
  .Include("Comments.CommentType")
  .Include("Comments.Owner")
  .Include("Comments.Message")
  .Where(m => m.RID == messageId)
  .SelectMany(m => m.Comments)
  .Where(c => c.CommentType.Id == commentTypeId)
  .ToList();
```

How I should rewrite this query?

P.S. I'm using EF 3.5 (not 4.0)

Comment: Are you telling me that no one has answered 6 of your 9 questions?

Comment: I need to know what's wrong in this case. And why include doesn't work.

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on... what do you expect this to do, what is it doing, what does your data model look like, ...

Comment: Yannick, I expect that the Comment entity will have CommentType, Owner and Message properties will be loaded. This query returns the correct set of comments, but they have empty properties. And I want to push EF to load these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely related to an [issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) with Include and joins. Basically it comes down to this: Includes are only applied at the end of the statement, and due to joining, the type of your query changes from an `IQueryable<Message>` to an `IQueryable<Comment>`.

By removing the join, it should correctly include the navigation properties. Try the following:

```
ctx.Comments
   .Include("CommentType")
   .Include("Owner")
   .Include("Message")
   .Where(c => c.Message.RID == messageId && c => c.CommentType.Id == commentTypeId)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Yannick, I have read post on MSDN, but I have still don't understand why in the following query include() not work:                var messages = ctx.Messages.Include("Account");
                var previews = ctx.MessagePreviews;

                var query = from m in messages
                            join p in previews on m.IDALIAS equals p.IDALIAS
                            where m.Id == messageId
                            select new Pair<Message, MessagePreview> { First = m, Second = p };

Comment: As far as I understood, it has to do with the way Includes are applied. Apparently when the resulttype of the query changes by joining(`SelectMany`), EF will not apply the includes.