# EF6 include with join not including.

Tags: entity-framework

I'm well aware this is an issue with a clear solution in more simple situations,
but i have implemented something that i think doing it otherwise 
or changing it completely due to this issue is wrong, 
maybe there is something that I don't see.
well, I have clients, each client have missions,each mission has agents assigned to it.
I want to load all that to an object, and to query on those parameters according to some search object i get from my client, like this.

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetMissionsBySearch(MissionSearchCriteria search, int loggedUserId)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
       try
        {
            var query = from mission in context.Missions.Include("AssignedAgents")
                join client in context.Clients on mission.ClientId equals client.Id
                select new
                    {
                        mission,
                        client.Name,
                        client.Office,
                        client.Id,
                    }
                into x
                select x;

            if (search.ByType != ActivityType.All)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.ActivityType == search.ByType);
            }
            if (search.IsTakenCareOf != "all")
            {
                bool endedOrNot;
                bool value = Boolean.TryParse(search.IsTakenCareOf, out endedOrNot);
                if (value)
                {
                    query = query.Where(s => s.mission.TakenCareOf == endedOrNot);    
                }

            }
            if (search.ByCreator == ByCreator.Me)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.AddedbyUserId == loggedUserId
                    && s.mission.AssignedAgents.Count(a => a.Id == loggedUserId) > 0);
            }
            if (search.ByCreator == ByCreator.Other)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.AddedbyUserId != loggedUserId 
                    && s.mission.AssignedAgents.Count(a => a.Id == loggedUserId) > 0);
            }
            if (search.ByCreator == ByCreator.Both)
            {
                //query = query.Where(s => s.mission.AddedbyUserId == loggedUserId
                //   || s.mission.AssignedAgents.Count(a => a.Id == loggedUserId) > 0);
                //query = query.Where(s => s.mission.AddedbyUserId != loggedUserId
                //   && s.mission.AssignedAgents.Count(a => a.Id == loggedUserId) > 0);
            }
            if (search.ByDate == ByDate.All)
            {
                //Doing Nothing
            }
            if (search.ByDate == ByDate.Today)
            {
                query = query.Where(s=> s.mission.Deadline.Value <= today);
            }
            else if (search.ByDate == ByDate.Yesterday)
            {

                var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.Deadline > yesterday
                    && s.mission.Deadline < today);
            }
            else if (search.ByDate == ByDate.LastWeek)
            {
                var lastweek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8);
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.Deadline > lastweek
                    && s.mission.Deadline < today);
            }
            else if (search.ByDate == ByDate.ByDays && search.Days > 0)
            {
                var daysBack = DateTime.Now.AddDays(search.Days*-1);
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.Deadline > daysBack);
            }
            else if (search.ByDate == ByDate.BetweenDates)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.mission.Deadline > search.FromDate && s.mission.Deadline < search.ToDate);
            }
            else if (search.ByDate == ByDate.EveryThingBackToDate)
            {
                query = query.Where(s =>  s.mission.Deadline < search.ToDate);
            }              
            return query.ToList();
```

I read those three articles and still have no success in getting this to work,
[Entity Framework & Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915786/entity-framework-include)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx
http://itsharpau.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/entity-framework-4-query-with-include-doesnt-work-with-join/

Please help,
Thank You.

Comment: The include not including "AssignedAgents", How can I achive that \ Get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` never works if you project to an (anonymous or named) type. Think of it, in which class should EF include the child collection?

The include will work if you do

```
var query = from mission in context.Missions.Include("AssignedAgents")
    join client in context.Clients on mission.ClientId equals client.Id
    select mission
```

Then EF will have `Mission` objects for which it can load `AssignedAgents` collections.

If you don't want to get the full objects you can get the same effect by incorporating `AssignedAgents` as a property in the anonymous type:

```
var query = from mission in context.Missions
    join client in context.Clients on mission.ClientId equals client.Id
    select new
        {
            mission,
            client.Name,
            client.Office,
            client.Id,
            Agents = mission.AssignedAgents
        };
```

Comment: The second option of incorporating AssignedAgents, works perfectly, but what you said at the beginning makes sense, I'll refactor to the first suggestion, Thank you!.