# Eager Loading with join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a query that joins two tables that do not have a defined relationship in Entity Framework, and where the joined table has a one-to-many navigational property to a third table.

There is a one-to-many relationship between msg and job, but there isn't a foreign key, and there isn't an association defined in the .EDMX.

There is a one-to-many relationship between job and lock, and there is an association defined in the .EDMX, so job has a job.locks navigation propertym and lock has a lock.job navigation property.

My original query:

```
var msgsAndJobs = (
    from m in dbContext.msgs
    join j in dbContext.jobs
        on new { jobid = m.jobid, priority = m.priority }
        equals new { jobid = j.jobid, priority = j.priority }
    where m.msgtype == "EMERGENCY"
    orderby new { m.recvdt }
    select new { m, j }
    );
```

I'm finding that EF is generating one query for the join, then executing a second query to populate the navigational property for each and every record returned by the join.

Microsoft's docs explain the issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

So I thought that I'd be able to use an .Include() clause, to eagerly load the records involved. But it doesn't seem to be working:

My new query:

```
var msgsAndJobs = (
    from m in dbContext.msgs
    join j in dbContext.jobs.Include("locks")
        on new { jobid = m.jobid, priority = m.priority }
        equals new { jobid = j.jobid, priority = j.priority }
    where m.msgtype == "EMERGENCY"
    orderby new { m.recvdt }
    select new { m, j }
    );
```

And it's still generating a query for each job lock.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `using System.Data.Entity;` will add support to lambda expression overload of `Include`

Comment: That got the lambda expression working, but the query is still lazy loading...

Comment: Have you tried just doing a projection for locks without the include or even better...manually add your join to locks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the problem with `Include`. It's too easy to make it ineffective and it's not always clear why it doesn't work. One thing that breaks an `Include` is [changing the shape of the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308569/861716). Another one is [projecting to a non-entity type or an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081793/861716).

This seems to make it incredibly hard to predict when `Include` does and doesn't work, but there is one simple trick: **`Include` always works if you apply it at the end of the query.**

If you can't apply it there, it wouldn't have been effective anyway.

With this in mind, if we look at your case, it's clear why `Include` doesn't work. You can't do

```
(... select new { m, j }).Include("locks"); // Runtime error
```

because `locks` isn't a navigation property of the anonymous type, obviously. It's more evident if you use the lambda version:

```
(... select new { m, j }).Include(x => x.locks); // Doesn't compile
```

So your `Include` is ineffective and the `locks` are loaded on demand.

Fortunately, there is a way out due to **relationship fixup**, the process by which EF knits together entities in the context by their navigation properties. Change your query into this:

```
var msgsAndJobs = (
    from m in dbContext.msgs
    join j in dbContext.jobs
        on new { jobid = m.jobid, priority = m.priority }
        equals new { jobid = j.jobid, priority = j.priority }
    where m.msgtype == "EMERGENCY"
    orderby new { m.recvdt }
    select new { m, j, j.locks }
    ).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new { x.m, x.j });
```

If you execute this query, `.AsEnumerable()` causes the result to be loaded into the context, after which you can select the result you originally wanted. Now you'll notice that EF has populated all `job.locks` collections.

One important thing though: you have to **disable lazy loading**, otherwise addressing a `job.locks` collection will still trigger lazy loading. This is because, even though the collection is populated, it is not marked as `Loaded` internally.

Comment: @GertArnold - I am following the pattern you describe above and the navigation property is not populating. Thus, it is not working for me.

Comment: Maybe it's worth a new question.

Comment: thanks for your sentence: "Include always works if you apply it at the end of the query"