# System.Linq.Dynamic - No property or field exists in type ICollection

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic with EntityFramework. My entities are below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        CustomerInterests = new List<CustomerInterest>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerInterest> CustomerInterests { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerInterest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my method:

```
public dynamic Get(long customerId)
{
    var query = DbContext.Customers.Include("CustomerInterests").Include("CustomerInterests.Course").AsQueryable();

    return query.Where(filter => filter.Id == customerId).Select("new(id,name,customerInterests)");
}
```

JSON result:

```
  {
    "id": 2003,
    "name": "name customer",
    "customerInterests": [
      {
        "customerId": 2003,
        "courseId": 2,
        "course": null,
        "id": 2016        
      },
      {
        "customerId": 2003,
        "courseId": 3,
        "course": null,
        "id": 2017
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying to load the property `Course`, but it's always returning `null` as you can see in JSON result.

How can I create the selector `new(....)` to load correctly the property `Course`. I've already tried `new (customerInterests.course) as customerInterests.course` without success. 
Do not forget that I am trying to navigate `Customer` (object) -> `CustomerInterests` (Collection) -> for each item load `Course` (object).

I would appreciate if you could help me on this matter.

Comment: You project the query to an anonymous type. [Include never works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081793/861716) if you project the results.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree with you. I just add the Include to make easier the question, but actually the focus is how write correctly the selector new (...). =)

Comment: I don't think that's possible with dynamic LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced that before, and my conclusion is: in Lambda extension methods you can load only 1st level of related object.
You can get list of customerInterests but you can't get foreign records for this list.
But you may use LINQ query instead.

```
var query=from c in DbContext.Customers
from ci in c.CustomerInterests
from co in ci.Courses 
where /// your conditions 
select new {
id=c.id,
name=c.name,
customerInterests= new {
customerId= ci.customerId,
courseId=ci.courseId ,
courses= new {
Name=co.Name
/// Other Courses attributes
}
}
}
```

**EDITED**
If you're using EF7 , you're able to load second level of foreign records by using ThenInclude method

```
db.Customers.Include( customer => customer.Orders). ThenInclude( order=> order.OrderDetails);
```